# How to convert column data type from float to string in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to fix this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ....
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to float. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[SQL: INSERT INTO all_sites_he (vendor, site_id) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: (('ESN', 4), ('ESN', 5), ('ESN', 7), ('ESN', 8), ('ESN', 9), ('ESN', 10), ('ESN', 11), ('ESN', 12)  ... displaying 10 of 500 total bound parameter sets ...  ('ESN', 723), ('HUA', 724))]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and here's my code part:

```
    def prepare_data():
        """Create DataFrame and clean column names."""
        jobs_DF = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),all_sitesexcel), usecols=['Vendor','Site_ID'], sheet_name='Sheet2')
        new_columns = [column.replace(' ', '_').lower() for column in jobs_DF]
        jobs_DF.columns = new_columns
        kanban_sites = 'Site Integration Kanban_Netherlands KPN Mobile Network Modernization Project__20200207225328.xlsx'
        hua_sites_df = pd.read_excel(kanban_sites, sheet_name='gsclist1', header=1)
        jobs_DF['vendor'] = jobs_DF["vendor"].round(4).apply(str)
        jobs_DF['vendor'] = np.where(jobs_DF.site_id.isin(hua_sites_df['Site ID']),
                                             "HUA", "ESN")
        return jobs_DF
```

So All I need after reading this dataframe I want to update column `vendor`

How can I solve this error then?

Comment: Did you try with `.astype(str)` ?

Comment: @CeliusStingher yes I tried give me the same error also

Comment: @CeliusStingher I think I have to create a `MetaData` for this case?, I think I have to create a dictionary for this

Comment: @CeliusStingher solved by changing the datatype in the excel it self

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Pandas should be enough to solve it. Also, how did you code your `.astype(str)`, redifining the columns/df right? Because the default behaviour is `inplace=False` I think

Comment: its a string to number conversion error.

Comment: So the other way around, you need a string to be converted into float?